# Create an HTML input id dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a id for input dynamically,

I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model[3].Count; i++)
      {
      @Model[3][i]
    terminal = "terminal" + i;

                        <input type="text" name="@terminal" id="@terminal"  onblur="return call()" />


      }
```

but with no success.

**EDIT:**

when i try:

```
function call() { alert(document.getElementById("terminal").value); }
```

i get null value. 
but for another element like  
that is not in loop and the id is assigned static it is OK.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

my model,  is

```
 List<List<string>>
```

the teminal value will be assigned as :
 terminal0 
terminal1 
. 
. 
terminal(n) 
in the FormCollection on the controller it is ok, im getting correct values the problem is when i try with DOM in JavaScript, i get NULLs

Comment: Why does that not work?  What is the specific issue you are having.

Comment: when i try:
function call() {
            alert(document.getElementById("terminal").value);
        }
i get null.
but for another element like
 <input type="text id="test" name="test"/>
that is not in loop and the id is static
it is ok.

Comment: Considering there is no element with id of `terminal` that is working as expected.  The id's are `terminal0`, `terminal1`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your javascript.  It should be:

```
function call() { alert(document.getElementById("terminal0").value); }
```

You are creating the id value as: `terminal = "terminal" + i;` which will produce `terminal0`, `terminal1`, etc.  All of this can easily be verified by viewing the source on the html produced by your page.

Comment: This is correct, it was my bad i mixed up from all the testing.
work perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting?

are you counting the data in the [3](3rd array) model? or are you trying to instantiating it?

if you are instantiating the model and setting 3 spaces then I think its better to do it before you do the for loop with an identifier, and use identifier.count so it becomes clearer.
for example.

```
Model[3] model;

for (int i = 0; I < model.count; i++)
```

in this way its set to 3 and i will count to 3.

if your counting the model in the 3rd array (Model[3].count)
im not sure if that is possible. if it is make sure its an integer.

hopefully this helps.

Comment: There is no problem with my model, it is  List<List<string>>
the teminal value will be assigned as :
terminal0
terminal1
.
.
terminal(n)

in the FormCollection on the controller it is ok, im getting correct values
the problem is when i try with DOM in JavaScript, i get NULLs

Comment: hmm..maybe its just me but I also had trouble with javascript getting updated values from a dynamic element before.